# Flatten array to use array_key_exists on a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `php` array that looks like this...

```
(
    [name] => Test
    [age] => 50
    [items] => Array
        (
            [23456] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12
                )
            [3345] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 344
                    [status] => stock
                )
            [2236] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 876
                )
        )
)
```

I am trying to search for any mention of `status` in the `items` section of the array.

I have tried using `array_key_exists` like this...

```
array_key_exists('test',$arr);
```

But this is giving me false, as an alternative I was thinking of flattening the array somehow and then searching to make it work with my array.

Is this the best choice?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use also use [`array_column()`](https://php.net/array_column) to see if the key exists :

```
$exist = !empty(array_column($arr['items'], 'status'));
```

But, @Barmar answer could be more efficient on large arrays.

Comment: This is nice, array is only ever going to be very small so this is nice and compact

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the `items` array and check each item.

```
function status_exists_in_items($arr) {
    foreach ($arr['items'] as $item) {
        if (array_key_exists('status', $item)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter the array and handle just those items, that have a `status` key.

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'Test',
    'age' => 50,
    'items' => [
        23456 => [
           'id' => 12,
        ],
        3345 => [
            'id' => 344,
            'status' => 'stock',
        ],
        2236 => [
            'id' => 876,
        ],
    ],
];

$result = array_filter($data['items'], function($item) {
    if (isset($item['status'])) return $item;
});

var_dump($result);
```

Results into:

```
array(1) {
    [3345] => array(2) {
        ["id"] => int(344)
        ["status"] => string(5) "stock"
    }
 }
```

This solution could be slow (as every function that handles native arrays) depending on how big your array is. You can work with [filter iterators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.filteriterator.php), which work as yields and do not consume as much memory as arrays do.